# Receiving post data xml

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

Hi I need to receive a post data which will be in an xml that is encoded in a base64 format.
I'll be receiving this  from a payment gateway. Now all i get is this. My code creates a txt file but is empty. Is there anything wrong with the code? The output should be an xml envelope in a text file.

```
$body = '';
$fh   = @fopen('php://input', 'r');
if ($fh)
{
  while (!feof($fh))
  {
    $s = fread($fh, 1024);
    echo $s;
    if (is_string($s))
    {
      $body .= $s;
    }
  }
  fclose($fh);
}

$body = base64_decode($body);

$ourFileName = "testFile.txt";
$ourFileHandle = fopen($ourFileName, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fclose($ourFileHandle);
$myFile = "testFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");

$stringData = $body;
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
```

I tried to contact the payment gateway and they are telling me that they are getting this error "The remote server returned an error: (417) Expectation failed." where could the problem exist us or them?

Comment: Am I misreading this? Would $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA work instead of populating $body from php://input? What error (if any) comes when you remove the @ from fopen?

Comment: hi @ChrisK Thank you! I've tried $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA but it is still a blank text file, also i've tried to remove the @ from fopen, no errors and still a blank text file.

Comment: @ChrisK i also tried to echo `$fh` just to see if it contains something. It displays "Resource ID #2".

Answer (score 0):

Since your file is returning blank, I would recommend verifying the specifications from the payment gateway for your fopen() function. In addition, if you are properly getting data back from them, then I would check the base64_decode() function. I have seen situations where there may be a header or other data at the top of the actual payload data that fouls up the base64_decode and ruins your day.

Comment: I have seen payment gateways where you send them a post request and they respond. I assume he is working in that direction, otherwise you are correct.

Comment: hi you are correct i'm following that flow. I am sending them a post request then they respond. Also there are no headers above the code so i am sure that there are no problems with headers.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are mixing up your file handlers, can you see if the following codes run:

```
$body = $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA;
$ourFileName = "testFile.txt";
$ourFileHandle = fopen($ourFileName, 'w') or die("can't open file");

$stringData = $body;
fwrite($ourFileHandle, $stringData);
fclose($ourFileHandle);
```

I have just tested the above code myself successfully.

What I suggest you do is trying the following:

- Try to put a static piece of data into $body (eg: "$body = 'test';")- and see if that saves - if not then it is an issue at your end.
- Delete the file (to remove any permission issues).
- Double check the url that the payment gateway is sending to is correct.

Comment: Hi i have tested this code. I expected that the body will be a base64 encoded string since this is what they are sending to me. But still im am getting a blank response.

Comment: @kiel Added some suggestions.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion i tried the first one. It is also blank so we managed to see if there is a firewall block in our host. As expected it is. There was a few things adjusted and everything went fine. Thanks all!